# How do I get all the errors for a single JSON request (Bad Request) in a go in POSTMAN?

Tags: json, postman

Hope you are doing well!

In a functional testing, if I'm passing the invalid values in multiple fields in a JSON request, can POSTMAN show all of the errors in a single response?
I'm getting a single error message, although the request contains multiple invalid attribute values.

Thanks in advance!!

I'm getting only a single message at a time. After correction, I'm getting a different error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each Postman test block (pm.test) can have multiple assertions, but the first assertion to fail will cause the test to fail and will stop executing any more code in that block.

Postman uses [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for its assertion library, and this does not have the concept of soft assertions.  The test block either passes or it fails.

If you want feedback on all of the elements in your response, then these should be separate test blocks.